# Microsoft Azure based Audio conversion?

Tags: audio, azure, pcm

Does anyone know if its feasible to convert PCM/FLAC files to some compressed format (mp3/wma/ogg, not picky), **with the conversion process running on Azure**?

An Amazon EC2 based solution would be trivial, as 3rd party libraries could be installed; but what about Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Azure 1.3 one can now install basic software to web and worker roles by RDPing and installing.  For automated tasks a VM role can also be created.  Between the two, this could be solved.

Comment: Don't use RDP to install software as it is not persisted.  Next service heal and all your work would be gone.  That being said, you could use Startup tasks running as admin to install any necessary software.  If the installation was particularly long or arduous, then I would look at VM Role.

Comment: Yes, all of that is true - I just wanted to make a note that since I first asked the question this use case can be handled - either manually or scripted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need admin privileges (like to install a codec or something), this shouldn't be a problem in Windows Azure.  I bet you can find a standalone command-line tool for this that you can just run in Windows Azure.

That being said, I haven't specifically seen this done yet, so there might be difficulties I'm not anticipating. :)